Vercel not applying images and css
I recently built a static website for a friend of mine and asked me to use vercel to deploy it. When I did the webiste looks like this:https://links-eight-nu.vercel.app/
here is my github: https://github.com/adighiero1/links
I've tried redeploying the website. Checking the logs but it doesn't list any errors.

Check the console for errors? I see one

vercel is serving contents of index.html in place of style.css and script.js , you can check it through devtools(network or source tab)
maybe you should add specific routes to vercel.build
"routes": [
{ "src": "/style.css", "dest": "/style.css" },
{ "src": "/script.js", "dest": "/script.js" },
{ "src": "/img/(.*)", "dest": "/img/$1" },
{ "src": "/(.*)", "dest": "/index.html" }

],
if this dont work , maybe you messed up something is vercel configuration in backend
